# Webserver: NAS vs DAS

Tags: web-server, xen, network-attached-storage

Currently we have 1 server that runs a Xen 4.0 kernel (debian squeeze). On this server we run several virtual machines (2 webservers, 1 mailserver, samba server, database server) (HDD is configured in RAID-6)

Specifically for the webservers html data, I was woundering if it would increase the performance if this data would become a network mount (not virtual, so using another HDD).

Also for the database, would it be recommendable to migrate this virtual server to a dedicated server?

Thank you

Comment: First question: Do you experience any performance bottlenecks? If not, you might or might not increase the performance, but without any real benefit.

Comment: The only way that you'll get a real 'bottom line' performance boost (bottom line as opposed to a theoretical boost on some benchmark) out of improving something is by first proving that this is the slowest component of your system. There's little point in improving the disks if your biggest performance hit is coming from a bug/configuration issue with a badly performing network card driver, or inadequate memory, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the NAS, if it's an SSD-based multi-disk-R10 array over a 10Gbps link and your DAS is a 4 drive R6 of consumer 7.2krpm SATA 150 then the NAS will probably be quicker.

That's unlikely though, I'd imagine your NAS would be over a 1Gbps NIC compared to a 3Gbps local DAS, so it'd probably me much slower.

If you want to improve your DAS performance just add more disks and make it a R10 array instead.